# Can't view the images properly

Tags: javascript, css

I've created some js codes for scrolling images on the page, but cannot view all images. the problem happened on Google Chrome. is there any solution? I'm including the js code and css to this.

```
data=[
[" images/img1.jpg"," Image1","pic01.jpg"],
[" images/img2.jpg","Image2 ","pic02.jpg"],
[" images/img3.jpg","Image3","pic03.jpg"],
[" images/img4.jpg","Image4","pic04.jpg"],
[" images/img5.jpg","Image5","pic05.jpg"],
[" images/img6.jpg","Image6","pic06.jpg"]

]

imgPlaces=5 // number of images visible
imgWidth=158 // width of the images
imgHeight=100 // height of the images
imgSpacer=2 // space between the images

dir=0 // 0 = left, 1 = right

newWindow=0 // 0 = Open a new window for links 0 = no  1 = yes

// ********** End User Defining Area **********

moz=document.getElementById&&!document.all

step=2
timer=""
speed=30
nextPic=0
initPos=new Array()
nowDivPos=new Array()

function initIMGSCROLL(){

for(var i=0;i<imgPlaces+1;i++){ 
newImg=document.createElement("IMG")
newImg.setAttribute("id","pic_"+i)
newImg.setAttribute("src","")
newImg.style.position="absolute"
newImg.style.width=imgWidth+"px"
newImg.style.height=imgHeight+"px"
newImg.style.border=0
newImg.alt=""
newImg.i=i
document.getElementById("display_area").appendChild(newImg)
}

containerEL=document.getElementById("imgcontainer")
displayArea=document.getElementById("display_area")
pic0=document.getElementById("pic_0")

containerBorder=(document.compatMode=="CSS1Compat"?0:parseInt(containerEL.style.borderWidth)*2)
containerWidth=(imgPlaces*imgWidth)+((imgPlaces-1)*imgSpacer)
containerEL.style.width=containerWidth+(!moz?containerBorder:"")+"px"
containerEL.style.height=imgHeight+(!moz?containerBorder:"")+"px"

displayArea.style.width=containerWidth+"px"
displayArea.style.clip="rect(0,"+(containerWidth+"px")+","+(imgHeight+"px")+",0)"
displayArea.onmouseover=function(){stopIMGSCROLL()}
displayArea.onmouseout=function(){scrollIMGSCROLL()}

imgPos= -pic0.width

for(var i=0;i<imgPlaces+1;i++){
currentImage=document.getElementById("pic_"+i)

if(dir==0){imgPos+=pic0.width+imgSpacer} // if left

initPos[i]=imgPos
if(dir==0){currentImage.style.left=initPos[i]+"px"} // if left

if(dir==1){ // if right
document.getElementById("pic_"+[(imgPlaces-i)]).style.left=initPos[i]+"px"
imgPos+=pic0.width+imgSpacer
}

if(nextPic==data.length){nextPic=0}

currentImage.src=data[nextPic][0]
currentImage.alt=data[nextPic][1]
currentImage.i=nextPic
currentImage.onclick=function(){stopIMGSCROLL()}
nextPic++
}

scrollIMGSCROLL()
}

timer=""
function scrollIMGSCROLL(){
clearTimeout(timer)
for(var i=0;i<imgPlaces+1;i++){
currentImage=document.getElementById("pic_"+i)

nowDivPos[i]=parseInt(currentImage.style.left)

if(dir==0){nowDivPos[i]-=step}
if(dir==1){nowDivPos[i]+=step}

if(dir==0&&nowDivPos[i]<= -(pic0.width+imgSpacer) || dir==1&&nowDivPos[i]>containerWidth){

if(dir==0){currentImage.style.left=containerWidth+imgSpacer+"px"}
if(dir==1){currentImage.style.left= -pic0.width-(imgSpacer*2)+"px"}

if(nextPic>data.length-1){nextPic=0}

currentImage.src=data[nextPic][0]
currentImage.alt=data[nextPic][1]
currentImage.i=nextPic
/*currentImage.onclick=function(){his3Win(data[this.i][2])}*/

nextPic++

}
else{
currentImage.style.left=nowDivPos[i]+"px"
}

}
timer=setTimeout("scrollIMGSCROLL()",speed)

}

function stopIMGSCROLL(){
clearTimeout(timer)
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<body onLoad="initIMGSCROLL()">
<script src="style/imgscrolling1.js">
</script>      

  <div id="col_slideshow">
     <div id="imgcontainer" style="position:relative; left:1px; right:0px; top:20px; width:60px; height:100px;overflow:hidden">
          <div id="display_area" style="position:absolute; left:0px; right:1px; top:0px; width:60px; height:100px; clip:rect(0,0,0,0)"> </div>
    </div>
             </div><!--col_slideshow-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: edit your question, select your code, press ctrl+k, commit your edit, thanks.

Comment: I diddn't know that, I was always spacing 4 times per line :P +1

Comment: Sorry, but all I can make of this question is: Go hire a code reviewer.

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel?  I'd use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) with the [LightBox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) plugin.